# Is it required to have Apple OS X Macintosh to deploy iPhone App through App Store?

Tags: iphone

If I use third party package like PhoneGap and Titanium that allows you to develop native iphone app using plain javascript, css and html without using any object-c, am I still required by Apple to use Apple Mac OS X computer to actually deploy and go through Apple approval process of finished iphone App? Also the same question if I want to deploy iPhone app under development to my own iPhone for testing?

Answer (score 0):

When you completed your app, you are required to submit the application to Apple for approval to the app store.

You will be required to sign up an developer account with Apple to submit any application. A developer account is needed as well if you want to test it on an iphone. I'm not sure if 3rd party packages has a compiler to build to the iphone.

Comment: Please kindly read my question carefully. Your answer is not an answer to my question.

Comment: I am waiting for answer from experience Titanium or PhoneGap developer who has actually developed and went through Apple approval process with Apple without using Apple Mac OSX computer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to have a Mac OS 10.5 or higher computer to develop iOS applications on even if you are using Titanium.

The reason for this is Titanium needs to have access to the iOS SDK which you can only install on a Mac. Also, you need to have a mobile provisioning file which is used to sign the application. When you develop an app and wish to test only on your device, you still need to generate a provisioning profile.

If you could some how get Mac OS X running on a Windows machine, then it technically should be possible as long as you install XCode within the Mac OS environment. But I can tell you that you'll save a lot of time and effort buy finding a cheap or used Mac mini on Craigslist and working on that.